# What is the most secure way of decrypting a GPG message within a non ad-hoc OS?

Tags: gnupg

**Which method would you advocate to make sure the decrypted content of a GPG message is flushed after reading it?**

PS: I am currently decrypting messages from a non-permanent live CD ran offline so that I am certain everything is flushed when leaving the OS. How can I do the same within the OS I am currently running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do the same within the OS I am currently running

You can't.

However, you can come pretty close.

For example, under linux, you can make sure you're using an encrypted swap partition with a random key, so that if your computer swaps memory pages out to disk, they can't be retrieved once you power off.

Then you can decrypt the message on /dev/shm, which is a ramdisk; e.g. files stored there only exist in RAM and get automatically wiped once you cut power to your computer, and if you do an rm * on /dev/shm, the files are immediately lost. Note they might persist in RAM, even if no longer visible on /dev/shm, though.

This isn't foolproof, but unless you're specifically targeted, it should ensure your decrypted messages don't end up on your hard drive.